# Is there a case where "of the clock" is more appropriate then "o'clock"?

Tags: formality, contraction-vs-full-form

In formal papers, I've always been told to avoid contractions, but unlike "do not" versus "don't", I don't think that I have ever heard "of the clock" spoken aloud.

Is there a case (aside from time travel) where "of the clock" is more appropriate?

Comment: No one ever expands "o'clock". I'd bet a good proportion of the population couldn't, if you asked them to.

Comment: @DanBron  I actually do this in spoken conversation from time to time. It invariably results in either a confused look or an amused chuckle.

Comment: The formal versions of "2 o'clock" are "2 pm" (or 2 am) or "1400 hours". If necessary, also state what time zone you are using and if there is a daylight saving adjustment in operation.

Comment: In formal, written use, many terms exist that are never spoken aloud, often called 'sight words', 'dictionary words', etc. The phrase you're asking about is still, if very rarely, used in *both* spoken and written Present Day English, by those who *affect* a formal, archaic phrasing, those who use such phrasing as a community identifier, and others.

Comment: Conversely, you would never mention something about the hands of the clock by calling them the hands o'clock

Comment: The only time I can imagine "o'clock" being expanded is in an archaic or humorous sense.

Comment: i don't even know of a good reason to avoid contractions in formal writing. if you've got one, i'd love to hear it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the expansion is "on the clock" not "of the clock".

Comment: @Rathony, "Do not" is generally much more forceful than "don't", and still has lots of use in normal speech as a command. "Of the clock", on the other hand, doesn't normally have connotations not already included in "o'clock", so there's much less reason to use the unwieldy phrase. AJMansfield, [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=o%27clock) says it's "of the clock".

Answer (score 23):

The first reference the OED has to ***of the clock*** is from Chaucer's *Prologue* dated 1386 (presumably they had clocks).

> c1386   Chaucer Parson's Prol. 5   Ten of the clokke it was tho as I
>   gesse.

The most recent reference to *of the clock* is from Gladstone speaking in Parliament in 1884

> 1884   Gladstonein Parlt. 26 Feb. 2/5   That the Speaker..be presented
>   to-morrow at two of the clock in the House of Lords.

Various alternatives to *of the clock* have been used across the centuries. There is evidence for *of clock* 1473 & 1647; *a clock* 1584 - 1747; *at the clock* and simply *clock* 1509 - 1712. The first reference to *o'clock* in the OED is from Robert Southey - 1829

> 1829   R. Southey Roprecht 11,   From noon Till ten o'clock

**So, in answer to your question, there is no law against your using any expression you like, so long as it is decent and honest. But if you want to use *of the clock* you may be the first person to do so since the late nineteenth-century. But there is absolutely no guarantee that no one else has used it since Gladstone**
.

Comment: There is a clock dated to 1386 [still in existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salisbury_cathedral_clock).

Comment: What is the nature of the clock?

Comment: @deadrat If you click on Andrew's link you will be able to read all about it.

Comment: @WS2 You're kidding me, right?

Comment: @deadrat Well it's a Wikipedia article - believe what you will!

Comment: They may not have had many clocks, but they certainly would have had sundials. Maybe they referred to those as "clokkes." Though maybe not, as according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock the etymology of clock is related to bell. It says the escapement was invented arount 1300.

Comment: @steveverrill Yes it is interesting that there is really no word for 'clock'. *Cloche* in French is a bell. But the French themselves use *horloge* (from Latin *horologium* - relating to the science of timekeeping) or *pendule* relating to a part of a clock. It seems as if the clock was invented after creative language had ceased.

Comment: @WS2 What are you talking about? Someone created the word *clock* didn't they?

Comment: "Of the clock" has definitely been used more recently than 1884, though perhaps not in ordinary speech. Thomas Hardy's poem "The Oxen" begins: "Christmas Eve, and twelve of the clock"; I think it was published in 1915. But of course poets have always permitted themselves some archaisms for mood and/or metre.

Comment: @curiousdannii But it means *bell*! French *cloche* = bell. A French *horloge* is a clock - which is more logical since it relates to the science of timekeeping - but is still not a 'clock'.

Comment: @ws2 it means *clock* now, though.

Answer (score 16):

No. In Modern English, *o'clock* is not a contraction, and *of the clock* does not exist as an idiomatic expression. (It can occur literally, for example *I saw it on top of the clock*; but it doesn't exist in the sense of telling the time).

Comment: This is an unnecessarily didactic answer, and wrong to boot: "[Modern English is conventionally defined as the English language since about 1450 or 1500.](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/modengterm.htm)" // Distinctions are commonly drawn between the Early Modern Period (roughly 1450-1800) and Late Modern English (1800 to the present)." Further, even the OED does not consider the phrase "[cardinal numeral] of the clock" obsolete, but finds it is still retained in formal phraseology, about which the OP specifically asked. There are other PDE uses.

Comment: If 'Modern English' was changed to 'modern English' then Colin Fine's answer would be correct.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I don't think so. Even "contemporary English" doesn't get my vote. See the comment I made on the OP.

Comment: @JEL - Can you give an actual documented example of a community that currently and regularly uses the formulation "x of the clock"?  Most us have said the phrase at some time as a joke but I know no-one who does so regularly and seriously.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I can and will, for you. Observe that my evidence is given under protest, however: blanket and absolute statements that fly in the face of available evidence, evidence such as the mention of "formal phraseology" in the OED with reference to [cardinal] of the clock, **themselves** need to be supported, rather than baldly (and in this case, erroneously) stated as if they were *a priori* true. So, [UK Parliament](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/lords/2005/mar/17/preamble). The quotes in the OED are not meant to be comprehensive, but representative of claims made.

Comment: It is slightly misleading to say that the term “o'clock” is not a contraction in modern English, [it was a contraction](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/contractions), albeit an archaic one, the difference being that it has become fixed  over time.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase 'o'clock' is a linguistic fossil, and is never written as 'of the clock'.

It actually dates from the 14th century when clocks first started to be installed in churches to tell the hours. Before that, time had been computed by the position of the sun - there were twelve hours to the day and twelve to the night, so winter daytime hours were much shorter than summer daytime hours and winter nighttime hours. But hours in clock time are always the same length; so when you mentioned a time in the 14th century you needed to specify whether you meant 'three by the sun' or 'three of the clock', which could be very different times! But now we have been going by clock time for more than half a millennium, 'o'clock' no longer has that literal meaning and is just a tag to indicate that you are referring to the time.

Comment: Do you have evidence that that distinction was commonly made? I agree that it could have been, but I have never before encountered a claim that it was.

Answer (score 3):

*Of the clock* is used to mark time well into the 20th century, though it is largely limited to legislative record-keeping:

- [1902](https://books.google.com/books?id=yh06AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA633&dq=%22three+of+the+clock%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMI78i42d-ryAIVCZmACh3chwAI#v=onepage&q=%22three%20of%20the%20clock%22&f=false) (House of Commons)
- [1907](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yps-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=%22five+of+the+clock%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBmoVChMIpavC2uCryAIVAY0NCh1UlQwq#v=onepage&q=%22five%20of%20the%20clock%22&f=false) (New Zealand Legislative Council)
- [1925](https://books.google.com/books?id=WEkbAQAAIAAJ&q=%22three+of+the+clock%22&dq=%22three+of+the+clock%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBWoVChMIp_zB1N6ryAIVguCACh1LQA4p) (Newfoundland House of Assembly)

The phrase also appears in [*At Swim-Two-Birds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_Swim-Two-Birds), a 1939 novel by Irish writer Brian O'Nolan:

> I was acquainted of the way by angels, said the cleric, and the ladder [was . . .] conveyed to my college in a sky-carriage in the middle of last night, at two of the clock to speak precisely. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=kfD3lRpV9fsC&pg=PA180&dq=%22two+of+the+clock%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFYQ6AEwCWoVChMIy92EhN6ryAIVx4wNCh0m4gaK#v=onepage&q=%22two%20of%20the%20clock%22&f=false))

The difficulty in finding these examples, however, seems proves the opposite point: that *of the clock*, for the purposes of keeping time, is long obsolete, especially outside the formality of legislative bodies.

Comment: Also the UK Parliament, which used "of the clock" through at least the 2005-6 session, and at least in the [House of Lords debates](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld199697/ldhansrd/pdvn/lds06/text/61101-0001.htm#06110149000008). Surely, examples of contemporary use prove a phrase is *not* obsolete.

Comment: @JEL That's a good find; you could use that in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a formal paper I would use 9:00 rather than 9 o'clock, and '9 of the clock' is never used in practice.

Comment: What about "nine in the morning" ? No digits, no contractions no apostrophes and  no ambiguity.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "Nine in the morning" sounds informal (or at least imprecise) to me.

Comment: @Kevin  Well, 9 o'clock could be 9.00 p.m. and  it also depends on the context. If I have a business meeting, then 09.00 would be the most precise, but if I mentioned what time I arrived at work, then I see nothing wrong with "at nine in the morning".

Comment: @kevin I struggle to understand what is imprecise about "nine in the morning". To me, it means it one precise time and no other, while "9:00" could mean two different times. I also don't see why it would be considered informal. "She was at home in the morning" is certainly not informal, so i don't see why "It was nine in the morning" would be. A phrase can be common without being informal.

Comment: @sgroves: To me, it could be any time from 8:50 to 9:10 AM or so.  9:00 is always 9:00, particularly in 24-hour time, or when AM/PM is clear from context.

Comment: @Kevin That makes no sense. "at nine in the morning" means what it says. If you had a meeting scheduled "at nine in the morning", you're saying you would need more clarification on when it starts?

Comment: @sgroves: "I got to work at nine in the morning yesterday": I got to work at *around* nine.  "I got to work at 9:00 AM yesterday": I got to work at *exactly* nine.  Scheduling a meeting is a totally different situation because the context requires precision, and the fact that it hasn't happened yet means there's no room for "It was supposed to start at 9:00, but it actually started at 9:05, but we'll still tell people it was at nine in the morning."

Comment: @kevin Of course you can create ambiguity by introducing surrounding context. That's true of any phrase, though. "Nine in the morning" is still obviously less ambiguous than "9:00".

Comment: @sgroves: Assuming you're in a 24-hour locale, 9:00 is less ambiguous than "nine in the morning" for past events, as I just explained.  What's more, even in a 12-hour locale, context can easily imply the AM/PM so you don't need it.

Comment: I still disagree that it is (it's at least *as* clear). Again, context can make anything ambiguous. Keeping my -1 vote.

Comment: Avoiding ambiguity IMO is as simple as using 09:00.

Comment: As Sobrique says, I consider 09:00 and 9:00 to be very different things. 09:00 is 9 AM, 9 in the morning, etc. 9:00 could be 9 AM or 9 PM. Also, in engineering, we tend to use significant figures. So 9 AM is "roughly 9 AM", while 9:00 AM is "right at 9 AM". Technically, 9:0 AM would mean "plus or minus 10 minutes", but that probably wouldn't go over very well. You can't tell between 9:00 and 9 in speech, but if it matters, you can always specify "about 9 AM/in the morning" vs. "precisely 9 AM/in the morning". If everyone around uses 24-hour clocks, 9:00 would be understood though.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answers relating to the use of the expression in the UK Parliament, it's interesting to note that both the validity of the expression "… of the clock" and its archaism were brought out in this (perhaps vaguely humorous?) reference in the [House of Commons in 2001](http://www.theyworkforyou.com/debates/?id=2001-02-08a.1089.7#g1098.4):

> "By 3.30 this afternoon, or *half-past three of the clock* as my right
>   honourable Friend the Member for Bromley and Chislehurst (Mr. Forth)
>   *more correctly describes it*, we are supposed to have considered nine
>   detailed Government amendments."